# Left handside, left hand side, left hand-side?

Tags: hyphens, attributive-nouns, compounds

How do you write 'left hand side' and 'right hand side'?

Example:

> If necessary, select the review language from the language selection box in the left hand side menu bar (by default, the review language is English).

Answer (score 8):

It's "left-hand side", the side nearest the [left hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_right).

"Left hand" forms a *[compound adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Hyphenated_compound_modifiers)* and so should be hyphenated.

Comment: +1 Additionally, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/left-hand) defines *left-hand* as hyphenated word. (Although it remains open in Oxford, hyphenation rules still apply there because of how "uncommon" it is. As opposed to, say, an *ice cream sandwich* rather than an *ice-cream sandwich.*)

Comment: @JasonBassford- People write "ice cream sandwich"?  Savages.  What, do they think it's a cream sandwich with ice on top?